# Monitor data sent to windows service through windows form

Tags: c#, windows-services, client-server

I have a windows service that is installed on a server and act a server that waits requests from other clients(server-client), when it receives a request it handles it and log data sent to it in a text file and reply with acknowledgment to the client, other windows service which act as a client that send data to servers and log data sent and acknowledgment received in another text file.

I need to have windows form that monitor data transmitted between server and client.

ex: When server win service receives request message the win form will show it in text area and when the win service reply with acknowledgment also will be showed in the text area.

How can i implement this using C#

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where does asp.net come into the picture? What protocol are the server/clients using?

Comment: i am using TCP/IP and the windows service is implemented using C#

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how asp.net falls into this considering you explicitly ask for a windows form application, but I digress. There would be two logical ways,

1) Your winform monitors the log file from the servers windows service and appends to a textbox

2) You modify the servers window service to pass data to the windows form - a psuedo logging server.

Comment: The first solution is not perfect because i am logging each step in handling request message so i need to add a delimiter and each time new message is logged i need to read all lines to determine the last message received or sent, i defer this option till finding optimal one so explain more about the second option

Comment: @ahmy You can keep the byte position that was already processed, listed to file changes via a FileSystemWatcher, and only read/process the new data in the log file.

Comment: Yes this is a good solution for optimizing the first solution @thinkdevcode suggested but is there any optimal solution other than monitoring logged data ?

Comment: I have a new idea that to create a WCF service in the win form and the win service call this WCF then pass data to it and the WCF show it in the win form but how can this be implemented? how to host WCF in win application and when this WCF service is not running how long the win service will try to connect to it and to detect if it is running or not?